# DashJS with AWS PreSigned Urls

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3

I'm using [dashjs](https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js) to stream my audio files hosted in S3, what is the best way to have dash use presigned urls for this? Take in consideration that dash is used in the frontend and the urls must be signed in the backend.